# Would the induced current depend on the number of turns?

Tags: inductor

[image]

In this figure, let's say there was a switch on the A side. At the moment of closing the switch, would the number of turns in coil B make any difference to the current? I am saying that It won't matter cause increasing the number of turns increases the induced emf which go along with increasing the resistance by the same N factor. I am right, aren't I?

Source of the picture:
https://www.teachoo.com/10742/3114/NCERT-Question-14/category/NCERT-Questions/

Comment: What is `G` measuring?

Comment: Current induced

Comment: @Jack I rolled back your edits because the changes they made invalidated at least one of the answers that was given. At this site, that is discouraged. After an answer has been given, you should not edit the question in a way that makes an answer inappropriate. In this case, you originally asked about a switch, but then changed the question to one about an AC source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voltage is induced; current only flows if there is a load on the secondary and that is not clear from your picture. The device marked "G" **could be** a [galvanometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanometer) and that does measure current but, it also has a non-zero resistance that needs to be known in order to calculate current from the induced voltage on the secondary.

> *At the moment of closing the switch, would the number of turns in coil
> B make any difference to the current?*

More coils in B mean a higher induced voltage which means more current for a fixed value load. However, with such poor (and unknown) coupling, it's really hard to establish how this actually pans out. Of course, you could be talking about primary current so, there are a number of things that make it difficult to answer.

<sub>Any current that flows is due to induced voltage and load resistance. Also take note that for a magnetic circuit like this it is strictly incorrect to say current is induced. The current is a result of the induced voltage and load resistance. People will say I'm pedantic but, I'm just defending the standards I were taught many years ago.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Andy. Let's say the galvano has zero resistance and the only resistance out there is coming from the wire of which the coil is made. So, my question is with that all being said, would the current depend on the number of turns in coil B? I am saying it won't. What do you think?

Comment: @Jack if the coupling factor were known it could be solved. Not knowing the coupling factor of the two coils means I can't simulate it and make a better estimation. You have to remember that there are other things in play when the coupling isn't known.

Comment: Can't I say \$ I=\frac{N \dot{\phi_{m}}}{R}=\frac{N\dot{\phi_{m}}A}{\rho_{e}L}=\frac{N\dot{\phi_{m}}A}{\rho_{e}CN} =\frac{\dot{\phi_{m}}A}{\rho_{e} C}\$ where A is the cross sectional area of the wire and C is the circumference of the turn?

Comment: You don't know the coupling factor and you can't say this at all. For a good coupling factor (say unity), the peak-to-peak current (assuming a square wave driving source) would reduce by about 2:1 when the secondary turns halve. For a coupling factor of 0.5 the peak-to-peak current would rise by about 40% when the secondary turns halve.

Comment: Coupling does some non-intuitive things and you have to be prepared to solve the equivalent circuit (which I have). The numbers in the previous comment were from a 1 ohm load BTW and, I'm not going to go down testing any more scenarios. That's up to you and your simulator.

Comment: Let's assume an 0.2 quality factor, now how the situation will work out? What is the relation between the current in coil B and and its number of turns?

Comment: @Jack, I'm not going down another scenario. Best if you figure out a scenario yourself  then, draw the equivalent circuit and solve it in a simulator. A line has to be drawn somewhere, else the questions will never end. At that point, if you are still confused by something you should ask a new question about a specific scenario, possibly with an option of coupling factor and an option of secondary turns doubling.

Comment: I am sorry, let's keep your scenario of 0.5 coupling factor. Given, this coupling factor, how the number of turns is related to the current?

Comment: Well I did it with a 1 ohm load and 1 henry for the primary and 1 henry (then 0.25 henry) for the secondary. 0.25 henry is half the turns of 1 henry for a decent inductor. So, For a coupling factor of 0.5 the peak-to-peak current would rise by about 40% when the secondary turns halve as I said in a previous comment. But you also have to consider the settling factors. I used a 1 second period with 1 volt applied for 0.5 seconds. So many variables that you now must simulate this.

Comment: Then from this, we can take as a general trend in this specific case and say decreasing the secondary number of turns increases the current?

Comment: There isn't anything very general about this given the number of variables @Jack. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

When switch is closed in circuit A there will be a sudden change of electric field in circuit A. This will cause a sudden change in magnetic field and because of this sudden change in magnetic field there will a sudden voltage in circuit B as per Faraday law which states that a change in magnetic flux across the conductor induces volage in the conductor. If the number of turns in circuit B are more than the number of turns in circuit A then the induced voltage in circuit B will be more than the voltage in circuit A. Current in the circuit B will depends upon the load connected to the circuit B. As the change in current stops in circuit A the change in magnetic field will also stop and then there will be no voltage in circuit B. So in your case the voltage in circuit B will be induced right at the moment when the switch is is closed and after that there will be no voltage in circuit B as the current in circuit a becomes constant afterwards and because of this magnetic field will be constant.

Comment: The wire of which the coil B is made has a resistance. What I am asking is, would the current in the coil B depend on its number of turns? I

Comment: Yes.  If you are considering the resistance of the coil then the current will depends on the resiatnce as the current flows thorough the whole loop.

Comment: This not what I asked. What I am asking is, would the current depend on the NUMBER OF TURNS in coil B?

Comment: Of course as the number of turns increase then it means. that the length of the conductor is getting large and it increase the resistance.

Comment: I don't think so, because increasing the number turns also increases the induced voltage